# How to set icon in Cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile-development

I know this question gets asked a lot, and I'm still having trouble getting the icons to show in my app on ios and android after upgrading my platforms.

`cordova --version | 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)`
`cordova platforms | android 8.1.0 ios 5.0.1`

Following this https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html my first attempt was to add: `<icon src="res/icon.png" />` After building the app I see the images `Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset`.  But the images do not take in the app.

Next I generated all the necessary icon sizes and loaded them in `res/icon/android` and `res/icon/ios` and then added the following the icon references to the `config.xml` from the guide above.

Run `cordova build ios` and then I see the images `Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset` folder.  However still my icon is not set when I run the app in the simulator.

When I run `cordova build android` I get a build error: `AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.project.mine:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.`

Any ideas?

Edit: If I got into Xcode General -> App Icon Source and click the arrow to access App Icon.  I see the option to manually drag all my icons to the right spot.  I see all my icons have a warning: "The app icon set "AppIcon" has 22 unassigned children".  It looks like I can resize my images manually and drag them correctly.

I'm wondering if there is a automatic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Next I generated all the necessary icon sizes and loaded them in res/icon/android and res/icon/ios and then added the following the icon references to the config.xml from the guide above.

Did you do that by hand?

There's a package that does it all for you.

```sh
npm install -g cordova-res
cordova-res
```

You need the following file structure:

```
resources/
├── icon.png
└── splash.png
config.xml
```

Also: in Android, the icon is cached sometimes. You have to either restart your launcher or the phone. (maybe cleaning the app cache works too)

Comment: I actually used a different tool to generate them.  I think you might be onto something about the caching though.  I had to clear everything for a different reason and I noticed that all of my icons now work. Thanks!

Comment: So I noticed that the icon was missing from the notifications that were received and decided to give this tool a try.  It generated the icons properly.  But now I've lost my "app switcher icon".  I've tried to rebuild everything, but am not having any luck.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You mean the icon on top when you are switching apps? It should be there... probably still a caching issue...

Comment: Correct, that icon.  I was able to resolve that one now.  The only icon issue I still have is the notification icon.  It appears to work on certain devices, but others it's just a gray colored circle.

Comment: Saved me so much time, thank you! This is the right way to do it in Cordova as opposed to using online generators and manually updating config.xml